# subtracting and appending global variables to a new dataframe in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, global

I am trying to make a function that can find the minimum value from a squared distance calculation.

I have a large DataFrame `(df)` that contains a years worth of hourly forecast values for a series of 12 regions as well as corresponding historical values to compare with, a simplified version is presented below.

These forecasts are compared to the historical values region wise, but then aggregated. The minimum distance is then selected as a chosen value representative of the 'state' of the system.

**A simplified reproducible example:**

We have three DataFrames, one with the forecasts; `forecast_Hour_1` and two with the historical data; `Pool_Hour_1` and `Pool_Hour_2`.

```
        Pool_Hour_1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['BusinessUtc','Horizon','EvaluationUtc','BZ','Value'])
        date = pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01 00:00:00')
        day = timedelta(days = 1)
        date1 = date
        date2 = date - day
        date3 = date2 -day
        date4 = date3 -day
        Horizon = 'D-1'
        Horizonf = 'D-2'
        BZ = ['NO4','NO4','NO4','NO4','NO1','NO1','NO1','NO1','NO5','NO5','NO5','NO5']
        Values = [1301.681, 1271.479,1460.043, 1302.357,3412.155, 3611.549, 4042.706, 3756.527,1462.085, 4042.706, 3756.527,1462.085]
        Pool_Hour_1['EvaluationUtc'] = [date1,date2,date3,date4,date1,date2,date3,date4,date1,date2,date3,date4]
        Pool_Hour_1['BusinessUtc'] = date
        Pool_Hour_1['EvaluationUtc'] = [date2,date2,date2,date2,date2,date2,date2,date2,date2,date2,date2,date2]
        Pool_Hour_1['BZ'] = BZ
        Pool_Hour_1['Value'] = Values
        Pool_Hour_1['Horizon'] = Horizon
        forecast_Hour_1 = Pool_Hour_1.drop(index = [1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11])
        forecast_Hour_1['Horizon'] = Horizonf
        Pool_Hour_1.drop_duplicates(subset ='BZ' ,keep='first', inplace = True)
        Pool_Hour_2 = Pool_Hour_1.drop_duplicates(subset ='BZ' ,keep='first')
        Pool_Hour_2['Value'] = round(Pool_Hour_1.Value /3.4)
        Pool_Hour_1['EvaluationUtc'] = [date3,date3,date3]
        df = pd.concat([forecast_Hour_1,Pool_Hour_1,Pool_Hour_2], axis=0)
```

**These are just a couple of examples of the variables that are generated in this process for simplicities sake. In reality, I make 24 forecast variables and then an even larger number of historical 'Pool' variables, one for each hour in the date range selected by the function. So, for example, if the date range is `12/01/2023 00:00:00 : 14/01/2023 00:00:00`, there will be 48 hours and thus 48 'Pool' variables. The date range will be an adjustable parameter though so this number can fluctuate*

To make the forecast and pool variables I use the following script, where I create 24 variables each separately named `forecast_Hour_XX`, where XX is between 1 and 24 and in this case 289 Pool variables title `Pool_Hour_XX`

```
# Set date range
end2 = pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01 00:00:00')
begin = pd.to_datetime('2022-12-20 00:00:00')
end = begin  + timedelta(hours = 23)


# dictionary of types and their respective codes
types = {"forecast": "D-2"}
# array of hours from begin to end
hours = pd.date_range(begin, end=end, freq="H")

# loop through each to extract all forecasts
for t, code in types.items():
    # initial variable for filtered df
    globals()[t] = df[(df['Horizon']== code) ].reset_index(drop=True)

    # group based on mapping .EvaluationUtc with `hours`
    for j, k in globals()[t].groupby(
            globals()[t].EvaluationUtc.map(
                {h: (ind+1) for ind, h in enumerate(hours)}).
            fillna(0).astype(int)):
        globals()[f"{t}_Hour_{j}"] = k
        
types_D1 = {"Pool": "D-1"}
hours_D1 = pd.date_range(begin, end=end2, freq="H")
        
for t, code in types_D1.items():
    # initial variable for filtered df
    globals()[t] = df[(df['Horizon']== code) ].reset_index(drop=True)

    # group based on mapping .EvaluationUtc with `hours`
    for j, k in globals()[t].groupby(
            globals()[t].EvaluationUtc.map(
                {h: (ind+1) for ind, h in enumerate(hours_D1)}).
            fillna(0).astype(int)):
        globals()[f"{t}_Hour_{j}"] = k.drop_duplicates(subset ='BZ' ,keep='first')
```

Now I want to take the squared difference between each forecast hour `Value` and each pool hour `Value` for matching regions, and at the end sum all regional values together to get a single number for that hour.

So for example. `forecast_Hour_1.Value - Pool_Hour_1.Value` for each matching '`BZ'` e.g. First for `NO4`, then for `NO1` etc. This is then repeated for the next pool hour. i.e `forecast_hour_1 - Pool_Hour_2` region wise, and so forth for all Pool hours.

But we aren't finished yet, then we need to do the same calculation for the next forecast hour so `forecast_Hour_2 - Pool_Hour_1` for all Pool hours and all forecast hours.

I can do this by hard coding the variables like so:

```
    f1 = Pool_Hour_1.assign(Value=Pool_Hour_1['Value'].sub(Pool_Hour_1['BZ'].map(forecast_Hour_1.set_index('BZ')['Value'])))
    f2 = Pool_Hour_2.assign(Value=Pool_Hour_2['Value'].sub(Pool_Hour_2['BZ'].map(forecast_Hour_1.set_index('BZ')['Value'])))
```

But really I want to generate the results automatically in a DataFrame where I can look at the results and select the minimum value. Any tips about hos I should go about this?

Really I need to find a good way of calling the global variables to make the calculations. Is this also bad practice?

Comment: If at any point you find yourself creating that many variables, it probably means bad practice. Make use of pandas functionality, calculate everything and return in an understandable form… you have lists, dictionaries, or even pandas Series. There is definitely no need for so many globals…..

Comment: My main issue is figuring out how to generate the results without specifically writing out the hard coded variables, maybe you could direct me to something useful?